# Getting death row inmates' last statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pandas

Initial version of the code appeared as an answer to an SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64868937/how-to-scrape-a-table-and-its-links/64873079). I refactored the code a bit and it works pretty well, IMHO. I get a solid `.csv` file with all the data from [Texas Department of Criminal Justice's Death Row](https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html) page.

What I was especially interested in was getting all offenders' last statement, if there was any, which the codes accomplishes.

What I'd want to get here is some feedback on utilizing `pandas`, as I'm relatively new to it. Also, some memory efficiency suggestions would be nice too, I guess.

For example, should I save the initial version of the `.csv` file and then read it so I can append the last statements? Or keeping everything in memory is fine?

If you find any other holes, do point them out!

The code:

```
import random
import time

import pandas as pd
import requests
from lxml import html

base_url = "https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row"
statement_xpath = '//*[@id="content_right"]/p[6]/text()'


def get_page() -> str:
    return requests.get(f"{base_url}/dr_executed_offenders.html").text


def clean(first_and_last_name: list) -> str:
    name = "".join(first_and_last_name).replace(" ", "").lower()
    return name.replace(", Jr.", "").replace(", Sr.", "").replace("'", "")


def get_offender_data(page: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.read_html(page, flavor="bs4")
    df = pd.concat(df)
    df.rename(
        columns={'Link': "Offender Information", "Link.1": "Last Statement URL"},
        inplace=True,
    )

    df["Offender Information"] = df[
        ["Last Name", 'First Name']
    ].apply(lambda x: f"{base_url}/dr_info/{clean(x)}.html", axis=1)

    df["Last Statement URL"] = df[
        ["Last Name", 'First Name']
    ].apply(lambda x: f"{base_url}/dr_info/{clean(x)}last.html", axis=1)
    return df


def get_last_statement(statement_url: str) -> str:
    page = requests.get(statement_url).text
    statement = html.fromstring(page).xpath(statement_xpath)
    text = next(iter(statement), "")
    return " ".join(text.split())


def get_last_statements(offenders_data: list) -> list:
    statements = []
    for item in offenders_data:
        *names, url = item
        print(f"Fetching statement for {' '.join(names)}...")
        statements.append(get_last_statement(statement_url=url))
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 4))
    return statements


if __name__ == "__main__":
    offenders_df = get_offender_data(get_page())
    names_and_urls = list(
        zip(
            offenders_df["First Name"],
            offenders_df["Last Name"],
            offenders_df["Last Statement URL"],
        )
    )
    offenders_df["Last Statement"] = get_last_statements(names_and_urls)
    offenders_df.to_csv("offenders_data.csv", index=False)
```

The scraping part is intentionally slow, as I don't want to abuse the server, but I do want to get the job done. So, if you don't have a couple of minutes to spare, you can fetch the `offenders_data.csv` file from [here](https://yadi.sk/d/uSUMXxGv6bUMYw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Types

Here:

```
def clean(first_and_last_name: list) -> str:
```

`list` should more specifically be `List[str]`.

### Fluent syntax

Consider using fluent syntax for your `clean`, which - in this case - is basically just a reformat:

```
    return (
        "".join(first_and_last_name)
        .replace(" ", "")
        .replace(", Jr.", "")
        .replace(", Sr.", "")
        .replace("'", "")
        .lower()
    )
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate Shiny, I didn't know that!